# Glassfish v3 locking up under high load, thread pool issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, load, glassfish, locking

When putting our glassfish v3 server under some stress with a higher load, the machine stops responding after some time. This occurs in live conditions with real user requests in higher load situations with about 300 users accessing the site simultaneously but can easily be reproduced using siege within under a minute:

```
siege -t30m -c500 -d10 -i -f urlsInApplicationFrontEnd.txt
```

I tried tuning the max-thread-pool-size parameter (tried values between 16 and 512) but it doesn't really seem to have a noticeable effect besides decreasing request time or prolonging the time-until-lockup a bit.

After the machine stops responding (requests timing out), it can be brought back to life by changing the thread-pool-size which seems to reset some things:

```
asadmin set server.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.max-thread-pool-size=32
```

[Here's a thread dump](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18449425/threads.txt). Many threads are "TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock" but I am not quite sure how to interpret this.

I hope someone can help to address the issue - Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe it dependents on some other guys, check other external/internal modules, jndi resources, beans, etc....

Comment: most of your threads seems to be waiting for work to do... which thread pool is targeted by your "siege"? What is the CPU load on the system while it's not responding?

Comment: The targeted thread pool is the http-thread-pool assigned to the http-listener-1. System load was somewhere between 1 and 2, so no stress there (machine has 8 cores). I just did another test after performing some application tweaking to reduce response times. The application lived longer but also crashed harder - it had to be kill -9'd this time. Also, the stack trace was only obtainable using jstack -F. [Here is the new stack trace](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18449425/threads-2.txt).